# UDP Broadcasting/Responding - avoiding a DDoS-like scenario?

Tags: c#, networking, udp, broadcast

I want to implement a self-propagating system for distributing a small piece of data (IP address) across multiple client computers using a UDP broadcast & UDP response. To do this I'm using C# (`UDPListener` and `Socket`, see [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

It'll work something like this:

1. Client 1 broadcasts `What is the IP address?`
2. All other clients respond **to client 1** (not a broadcast) with their version of the IP address: e.g. `192.168.1.10`
3. Client 1 tests each IP address received and uses the most appropriate one

**My question is whether this short burst of responses would cause a significant bottleneck / DDoS-like effect on large networks? For instance, if 1,000 client machines all responded to client 1 simultaneously?**

EDIT: I'm not trying to create a DoS attack, I'm trying to avoid a denial of service scenario.

Comment: Unless the network is designed by smeone mentally challenged, you will NOT have 10.000 clients in one broadcast domain. THere are those, but they have problems anyway (network wise). Normally a C class network (i.e. the /24, 254 usable addresses) is quite a good size for a broadcast domain.

Comment: @TomTom Yeah, unfortunately you'd be surprised how many 'mentally challenged' people are put in charge of managing huge networks.

Comment: I agree, but then they already have performance problems. SERIOUS problems.

Comment: @TomTom What about with a broadcast domain of 1022 (/22)? Would that cause any network performance issues?

Comment: Not for that, but it theoreticall could - if you have any software. I rather normally limit my stuff to /24 and route between them ;) 1022 should not be too bad. I have oonce seen a complete university on ONE IP network complaining about their crappy performance.

Comment: Yeah, normally educational institutions are the worst in my experience. Thanks for your advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol), what you are trying to accomplish is already supported by NIC cards out of the box, for a DOS attack to succeed, packet should translate up the network stack where it consumes user/kernel-process space, CPU and/or other resources, when such packets are received at a faster rate than system can handle, it leads to Denial of Service.

Comment: As far as I know, ARP is for resolving link-layer (MAC) addresses from network-layer (IP) addresses. How would you use ARP to broadcast a custom message and receive a custom response? Say I wanted to ask 10,000 machines what `1+1` is, and receive a response from all 10,000 machines (presumably `2`)? (assuming all machines are running my software)

Comment: Simplistic. Seriously. You can also DDOS totally without the computer by overloading the network link. 10.000 clients can be a lot.